# jquery and validate does not work on click in laravel5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

First, I apologize for the bad English.
I am now using laravel(version 5.4.24) to create a voting button for site posts.

If I just use `<button>` in my code, it does not work when I click the vote button on the screen.
So, as an alternative, I passed the value using form, but this method does not seem to pass the value of json properly in validation.

The problem occurs in the "here" part,
If I delete the "here" part of `ArticleController.php` and click the button, it doesn't have the up or down value.
If I delete "part" and run it, the laravel will show the following error:

```
SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list' (SQL: SELECT sum (` `) as aggregate from` votes` where `votes`.`article_id` = 107 and` votes`. `article_id` is not null)
```

I've been looking for a way for a few days, but I have not found the answer.

Thank you for your help. Thank you.

show.blade.php

```
//<form ...> </ form> is code that was not in the example, but if I click on 
<button> without it, there is no response on the screen.(No redirects)
<div class="action__article">
<form action="{{ route('videos.vote', $article->id) }}" method="post">
@if ($currentUser)
{!! csrf_field() !!}
<button class="btn__vote__article" data-vote="up" title="{{ trans('forum.comments.like') }}" {{ $voted }}>
<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
<span>{{ $article->up_count }}</span>
</button>
@endif
</form>
</div>
```

*index.blade.php

```
@section('script')
@parent
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('vote')
 }
});

$('.btn__vote__article').on('click', function(e) {
  var self = $(this),
    articleId = $article['id'];
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/video/' + articleId + '/votes',
    data: {
      vote: self.data('vote')
    }
  }).then(function (data) {
    self.find('span').html(data.value).fadeIn();
    self.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    self.siblings().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
</script>
@endsection
```

*ArticleController.php

```
public function vote(Request $request, \App\Article $article)
{
   //"here" - The value received from the form will not pass here and will be redirected to the previous page.
    $this->validate($request, [
        'vote' => 'required|in:up,down',
    ]);

    if ($article->votes()->whereUserId($request->user()->id)->exists()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'already_voted'], 409);
    }

    $up = $request->input('vote') == 'up' ? true : false;

    $article->votes()->create([
        'user_id'  => $request->user()->id,
        'up'       => $up,
        'down'     => ! $up,
        'voted_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'voted' => $request->input('vote'),
        'value' => $article->votes()->sum($request->input('vote')),
    ], 201, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

$article=new App\Article;
$request= new App\Http\Requests\ArticlesRequest;

*model

```
class Vote extends Model
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'up',
        'down',
        'voted_at',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be visible in arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $visible = [
        'user_id',
        'up',
        'down',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'voted_at',
    ];

    /* Relationships */

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /* Mutators */

    public function setUpAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['up'] = $value ? 1 : null;
    }

    public function setDownAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['down'] = $value ? 1 : null;
    }
}
```

*database

```
MariaDB [mmdance]> desc votes
    -> ;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------------------               -+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                      |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------------------               -+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment                             |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                                            |
| article_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                                            |
| up         | tinyint(4)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                                            |
| down       | tinyint(4)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                                            |
| voted_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------------------               -+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what happens when you remove the in clause from validation because I feel there is an issue with that

Comment: Dhaval Chheda // when I remove the in clause from validation, when I click button, sql error occured(SQLSTATE [42S22]:).

Comment: try your code in php artisan tinker and see if there is an issue with your query because validation is passing ( it seems ) as it is hitting the database so please check and update  or you can add toSql() at the end of the query and it will echo the sql query and then you can debug the query from there

Answer (score 1):

problem lies here you are passing instance of `$request` here where you need to pass the field name like this

```
return response()->json([
        'voted' => $request->input('vote'),
        'value' => $article->votes()->sum('vote'),
    ], 201, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

[Click here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) to see how `sum()` works

Comment: pleasure bro I appears that you have found the answer by self isn't it?

Comment: if so please add your answer in the answer section I will upvote it thanks :)

Comment: please post your answer or accept my answer to close your question please check : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

It is because you may not have field in database table or you had not added any field in model like below.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'up',
    'down',
    'voted_at',
];
```

Comment: thanks your reply, I'm sorry, but I have field in database.